# Amtrak onboard announcement New York

Tags: field-recording, sharing

Hi all
A friend of mine is working on a little doc (not commercial) about his journey in the US (we live in Italy). He did  some field recording, but missed the Amtrak onboard announcement when his train arrived at the New York station.

Does anybody have that announcement recorded and doesn't mind to share it?

Let me know

Thanks in advance

Davide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tons from LIRR, track announcements, onboard, waiting area etc. Nothing Amtrak-specific but they are basically the same. Let me know if you are interested and I'll try to dig something up.

Comment: Thank you. It'll be great. What he's looking for is the announcement on a train when it's arriving in New York ("Next stop New York", something like that... I don't know never been in NY. Yet!) :)


Comment: Hmm. I know I have onboard announcements LEAVING NYC on the LIRR, and several track announcements from inside the station. Not sure about incoming onboard stuff. Will take a quick look. 

I live in Queens and I ride in and out of Manhattan all the time on the LIRR so I should be able to get you a "Next stop New York Penn Station" fairly easily. Hopefully that's helpful. 

Comment: @theodorejordan It is! if you can find/record that kind of announcements, they're perfect! ☺ maybe you can upload it to my soundcloud, or let me know where download it. If you ever need something from Rome, ask for it! ;)

Comment: @Davide Favargiotti Sorry I haven't responded to this for so long! Got swamped with a bunch of stuff the past month and forgot all about it. My bad. I will see what I can dig up for you this weekend if you still need them. :)

Comment: @theodorejordan Hi. I spoke with my friend a few days ago, and finally he's wrapping all the things up, so if you can send me those recording, it'll be much appreciated. soundcloud is ok? http://soundcloud.com/dieffe/dropbox/profile

Thank you so much

Comment: I dug up a handful, though they are pretty rough around the edges. Wound up sending you a Dropbox link instead. Let me know if you didn't get the message. Threw in a few station ambiences as well. Hopefully you can use some of them. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I have the announcement from the waiting lounge somewhere.  Would that work?

Comment: Don't know if it could work... He's looking for something like "Next Stop New York Central Station"... but maybe.. Anyway, thank you for taking the time to looking for it and sharing! Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem @Davide, that's why we're all here.

Comment: Thank you again, if you need something from Rome, let me know!